# How to copy and rename splitted *.rar archives with VBScript?

Tags: iis, vbscript, rar, filesystemobject, file-copying

I have a VB Script (*.vbs) on my server that check by the built-in FileSystemObject if a file like this exists...

```
"C:\path\{filename}.weekly.rar"
```

If it exists then copy the file in the same path but renamed as the following

```
"C:\path\{filename}.monthly.rar"
```

with this code

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists("C:\path\{filename}.weekly.rar") = True Then
    fso.CopyFile "C:\path\{filename}.weekly.rar", "C:\path\{filename}.monthly.rar", True
End If
```

Sometimes, the *.rar archive can be splitted in multiple files, so I have in the folder

```
"C:\path\{filename}.weekly.part01.rar"
"C:\path\{filename}.weekly.part02.rar"
"C:\path\{filename}.weekly.part03.rar"
...
```

How can I check if also the splitted files exists and then rename them in the same location like

```
"C:\path\{filename}.monthly.part01.rar"
"C:\path\{filename}.monthly.part02.rar"
"C:\path\{filename}.monthly.part03.rar"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue with the following code

```
Sub CopyRenamed(folder, find_str, replace_with)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim d : Set d = fso.GetFolder(folder)
    Dim f : Set f = d.Files
    Dim file
    For Each file In f
        If InStr(1, file.Name, find_str) > 0 Then
            fso.CopyFile file.Path, fso.BuildPath(folder, Replace(file.Name, find_str, replace_with)), True
        End If
    Next
    Set fso = Nothing   
End Sub
```